# Angular *ngFor doesn't find array

Tags: angular, local-storage, ngfor

I'm creating an array out of my localstorage entries and I am trying to let `*ngFor` iterate over them. Yet I'm mostly ending up with the following error:

```
Property 'characters' does not exist on type 'CharactersChecklistComponent'.
6 <div *ngFor=" let character of characters"> Hello</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your answers :)

```
Interface : 
    `export interface Icharacters{
        name: string;
        naxxramas25?: boolean;
        naxxramas10?: boolean;
        os10?: boolean;
        os25?: boolean; 
        eoe10?: boolean; 
        eoe25?: boolean;
        ulduar10?: boolean; 
        ulduar25?: boolean;
    }`
```

get all items from storage function :

```
`  allStorage() {
    var values = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;
    while ( i-- ) {
        let tempValue:any = localStorage.getItem(keys[i])
        let tempParsedValue = JSON.parse(tempValue)
        values.push(tempParsedValue);
    }
    console.log(values)
    return values;
  }`
```

getting character list in the component.ts :

```
`  ngOnInit(): void {
    var characters = this.CharacterfunctionService.allStorage()
    /* console.log(characters) */
    console.log(Array.isArray(characters))
    /* characters = characters as Icharacters[] */
    console.log(characters)
    }`
```

component html :

```
`<div *ngFor=" let character of characters"> Hello</div>`
```

tried implementing with and without interface which didnt really achieve anything mentionable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`characters` is not accessible from the HTML of your component if you declare the variable inside `ngOnInit()`. You would have to do something like this instead:

```
characters = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.characters = this.CharacterfunctionService.allStorage();
}`
```